# Mysql query, two tables. Select only if value exists in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, options and products. I want to select all from options but only if options.id exists in any of the products columns. This are my two tables:

options table:

```
id        option         value

1       'kategorija'    'Muški'
2       'kategorija'    'Ženski'
3       'kategorija'    'Dječji'
4       'brand'         'Casio'
5       'brand'         'Lorus'
6       'brand'         'Seiko'
7       'brand'         'Citizen'
8       'mehanizam'     'Quartz'
9       'mehanizam'     'Automatik'
10      'mehanizam'     'Eco-Drive'
11      'brojcanik'     'Analogni'
12      'brojcanik'     'Digitalni'
13      'grupa'         'Satovi'
14      'grupa'         'Naocale'
```

and the second table products:

```
 id     grupa   brand    mehanizam  brojcanik   kategorija  

10380   '13'     '4'        '8'        '11'         '2'
10560   '13'     '4'        '9'        '12'         '1'
11100   '13'     '6'        '8'        '11'         '2'
12380   '14'     '7'        '8'        '11'         '2'
12490   '13'     '6'        '9'        '11'         '1'
15720   '14'     '6'        '9'        '12'         '1'
16550   '14'     '5'        '8'        '12'         '3'
```

my attempt for query:

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE grupa="14" AND brand=options.id OR mehanizam=options.id OR brojcanik=options.id OR kategorija=options.id)
```

the result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [option] => grupa
            [value] => Naocale
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [option] => brand
            [value] => Citizen
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [option] => mehanizam
            [value] => Quartz
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [option] => brojcanik
            [value] => Analogni
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [option] => kategorija
            [value] => Zenski
        )
)
```

This is array only for one row for products id 12380 which is grupa 14. Array should go on for the rest of products where there is grupa 14 found in products row.
I don't know if this is possible only with mysql query. If it's not possible i will have to do comparison with php which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: why are options: `5`, `8`, `3`, `6`, `9`, `1` are not included?

Comment: not included where? In array?

Comment: the answer that was deleted works fine for me. Don't know why is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your statement,

> *I want to select all from options but only if options.id exists in any
>   of the products columns.*

You can combine all values using `UNION ALL` in a subquery and join the result with table `options`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    options a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  brand col FROM products WHERE grupa = 14
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  mehanizam col FROM products WHERE grupa = 14
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  brojcanik col FROM products WHERE grupa = 14
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  kategorija col FROM products WHERE grupa = 14
        ) b ON a.id = b.col
```

---

Much better way,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    options a
WHERE   EXISTS
        ( 
            SELECT  1 
            FROM    products b
            WHERE   b.grupa = '14' AND 
                    a.ID IN (brand, mehanizam, brojcanik, kategorija)
        )
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I'm struggling with this query for two days now and this works very good. Thanks

Comment: I'm so close. I have to use LIKE in two of the products columns. Is there a way to do it inside IN or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using specifically `14` you can simply join on `options` again

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products JOIN options ON id = grupa ...
```

Comment: sorry, but i cant't make a valid query with this. Can you please make a whole query?